# form.cleaned_data as a dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-forms, keyword-argument

Why when I call a function like this :

```
function(request, **form.cleaned_data)
```

I can send form's data as a dictionary, but when I try doing like this :

```
data = **form.cleaned_data
```

I'm getting error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `**` trick only works when a dictionary is expanded in a function call; you can't use it outside of a function call.